# How to group numbers by less than in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large table of data with lots of number values in a Pivot Table, I would like to group the values in the 'Weight' column, by:
values less than

```
1000
1500
2000
3000
4000
5000
6000
etc...
```

And then have a 'Count' column next to it, counting how many values there are that are less than 1000, less than 1500 and so on.  This is a very large table and will have thousands of values, which is why it'll be a lot easier to have them compacted down.  Thank you.

Current table:

```
Weight

3944      
3300
1000
2993
442
9388
2992
2281
2991
```

Desired table:

```
Weight   Count

<1000      1
<1500      1
<2000      0
<3000      4
<4000      2
<5000      0
<6000      0
<7000      0
<8000      0
<8000      0
<9000      0
<10000     1
```

Comment: Have you looked at frequency() ?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting problem to solve without adding any helper columns...

Here is what I would do:

[image]

```
=INDEX(
    FREQUENCY(
        $A$2:$A$10,
        RIGHT($C$2:$C$13,LEN($C$2:$C$13)-1)-1
    ),
    MATCH($C2,$C$2:$C$13,0)
)
```

I will start at the inner function and work outwards.

```
RIGHT($C$2:$C$13,LEN($C$2:$C$13)-1)-1
```

This takes the strings in the "Weight (upto)" column ("<1000" for example), removes the "<" symbol, and minuses 1 from the result (999 because we want "less than" 1000, not "less OR EQUAL TO" 1000).

Next, the FREQUENCY function takes 2 arguments.
The first is our range of actual weights.
The second is an array of the different cut off values for the groups to put those weights into (this is what we just produced with the formula above).

Because the FREQUENCY returns an array of counts, we have to use INDEX to select which particular value in the array we wish to return.
The first argument to INDEX is the array of values returned by frequency.
The second is the index of the value we wish to return. There are a number of ways which we could achieve this:

We could use ROW()-1, but then if you every move your table from the top of the sheet, it will break.
We could add a helper column (containing incremental numbers) to record "Weight Index", however, I like to minimize the number of helper columns where possible and in this case there is a fairly simple work around: MATCH

We simply use MATCH to return the index of the current weight group in the list of weights:

```
MATCH(<the current weight group>, <the complete weight group range>, <0 means we are looking for an exact match>)
```

I hope this makes sense. Things get complicated when you get into Arrays. If you need any further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Nice. The other option would have been to select D2:D13 (or D2:D14) and enter the middle part of the formula  =FREQUENCY(
        $A$2:$A$10,
        RIGHT($D$2:$D$13,LEN($D$2:$D$13)-1)-1
    ) directly as an array formula.

Comment: @TomSharpe I strongly dislike array formulas and avoid them where ever I can. Personal preference but I'd rather resolve any arrays within the formula, even if that means it is slightly more complex.

Comment: I agree actually. Would make more sense in Google Sheets with self-expanding arrays.

Comment: @Yuddy If my answer has answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. If it hasn't answered your question, please feel free to let me know why and I will do my best to help.